# Attainment of maximum

Tags: real-analysis

A basic result in real analysis is that a *continuous* function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ attains its *maximum* on $[0,1]$, i.e. there is $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=\sup_{y\in [0,1]} f(y)$.  A more advanced result is that the same holds if $f$ is only upper semi-continuous.

I am interested in which (more) general classes satisfy this kind of maximum principle.  In more detail, let $\Gamma$ be a class of real functions on the unit interval containing the upper semi-continuous functions.  For which (well-known) classes $\Gamma$ does the following principle hold?

*Let $g:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **bounded** function in $\Gamma$. Then there is $x\in [0,1]$ such that $g(x)=\sup_{y\in [0,1]} g(y)$.*

Is there a nice sub-class of Baire $\alpha$ satisfying this principle?  What about a nice sub-class of the cliquish or quasi-continuous functions?

Is there perhaps an answer if we replace the supremum by the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum)?  The latter amounts to the "supremum up to a measure zero set".

Comment: Of course no, let $f(x) = x, x < 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov It's not a yes or no question.

Comment: I am blind, I did not see the words "in $\Gamma$". Mea culpa.

Comment: I suspect that the result you are trying to prove is true provided $\Gamma$, as it is in the OP, is compact.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri what if $\Gamma = \{f\}$, where $f$ is as in Aleksei's comment?

Comment: I don’t think this can be answered meaningfully. Certainly upper semicontinuity is the correct condition for this to hold in general. More generally it suffices that it’s upper semicontinuous on the set $\{f  > c\}$ for some $c$ depending on $f$ such that the set is nonempty.

Comment: As it currently stands, there's no connection between the topology of $[0, 1]$ and $\Gamma$, so any suitable $\Gamma$ and a bijection on $[0, 1]$ will give another such $\Gamma$.

Comment: @user44191, the ordinary extreme value theorem for a continuous function $f$ similarly remains true if one applies an arbitrary permutation of the domain of $f$, so this is neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition is not well-known but may be of interest.  Since the function $g$ is bounded it has a supremum $M$.  The condition is that if $g(x)$ is infinitely close to $M$, then $g(st(x))\geq st(g(x))$ where "st" is the standard part (actually one can remove the second occurrence of "st").

Comment: The standard part map on the reals is of course not very constructive, but I see how this would work.

Comment: Hi @SamSanders, you haven't really clarified the reverse mathematics context of your *question* (this may be the reason for its initial reception).

Comment: The "reverse math" tag was added by accident; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @SamSanders, your comment above is incomprehensible without the reverse-math context.  As you know, infinitesimals in R can be done conservatively over ZF, so from the point of view of a traditional mathematician, there is no room for asserting that "standard part is not very constructive".  It is in SPOT.

Answer (score 1):

The following paper essentially shows that semi-continuity is optimal, i.e. one cannot expect to generalise the existence of a maximum beyond the upper semi-continuous functions (on compacts).

On Weierstrass extreme value theorem

Juan Enrique Martínez-Legaz

DOI 10.1007/s11590-012-0587-0